# Mac: I want to automatically copy a file that a process generates from one folder to another, rename the file and continue for 24 hrs, once a minute

Tags: shell-script, macos

I have a folder called `FolderA` and a folder called `FolderB`.

A process that runs in the background - not under my control - writes a file in `FolderA` every 1 minute or so.  It erases the previous file. There is always only one current file with a new name in `FolderA`.

I want to copy that file in `FolderA` to `FolderB`, rename it to `file1.jpg` and on the next run, as soon as the file in `FolderA` has changed, copy that new file to `FolderB` and call it `file2.jpg` and so on so that after N steps I have N files in `FolderB`, with the last file called `fileN.jpg`.

Can I do this as an automator script app?  Or how else?

Answer (score 1):

One can use [rerun](https://github.com/tartley/rerun) by installing it using `pip install rerun`

Then in the terminal, in the directory (FolderA) where the files to be watched are located, type:

`rerun "cp 1*.jpg /Desktop/FolderB"`

Automator script to rename files in FolderB can then run as it is not located in a Hidden Folder.

You may need `sudo` to run `pip`

Comment: You generally don't need `sudo` to run `pip`, running it as a regular user just means anything you install with it gets installed just for that user rather than globally.

Answer (score 0):

Automator? Maybe... I don't use it, so can't say if it will or not.

I do know that `launchd` can do it. The trick is creating the `.plist` file written properly so that `launchctl` will process it for consumption by `launchd`. That's a PITA because Apple does an incredibly sorry job with documentation (IMHO).

Fortunately, there's a 3rd party tool that takes up the slack - it's called [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com). I've used it to do something similar: I monitor a file for changes, and once a change has been detected, I launch `rsync` to do a backup. The support is great with LaunchControl also.

If my praise seems suspiciously enthusiastic, please know that it's not due to any affiliation with LaunchControl. Rather, my enthusiasm comes from the experience of having manually written & debugged a much simpler `.plist` file! It was one of the most frustrating nut-rolls of all-time. Never again...